# Active Notifying Workling randomly - IBM Worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have just tested the active notifying for my app, And i can observe the message set for active notifying throught IBM Worklight console pops up randomly and not always, Can you please help me to know why is the message not apperaning everytime i launch the App.

Thanks
Djrecker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to say without more details about the problem (such as server and device logs).  But one possible cause may be if, after the notification first pops up, you try it again before the JSESSIONID of the app's original session to the Worklight Server has expired.  In this case, the first time you run the app, the app will need to authenticate to the "wl_remoteDisableRealm" realm, which will cause the notification to pop up - then the next time the app is run, the session is still valid, so the authentication for the "wl_remoteDisableRealm" realm is still valid - so the notification does not pop up again.

One way to test if this is what is going on with your app is to reduce the server session timeout to a very small value.  Then run the app, and observe that the notification pops up.  Then exit the app, wait for the session timeout period to expire, and then start the app again and see if the notification pops up again.  Observe if this is consistently repeatable.  If so, that is what's going on.

Comment: Can you let me know how can we find or configure JSESSIONID value so that i can test this once.

Comment: You should change the "serverSessionTimeout" property (mentioned at http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/c_optimizing_and_tuning_of_ibm_wl_server.html?lang=en) to change the value of the session timeout.  You can set this in your Worklight project's "worklight.properties" file for testing with the development server, or by adding the appropriate JNDI environment entry on a production server.